# Replace double light switch

Tags: electrical, switch, light

You will see the old light switch has two common ports and 2 l1 and 2 l2. (Common wires removed on first pic). New light switch has com1, com2, l11, l12, l21, l22 - where do the wires go in the new switch?

[image: old switch]
[image: new switch]

*post-process attempt to perspective correct old switch. Still can't quite read it all*

[image]

Comment: What are the labels at the bottom we cannot see?

Comment: The labels at the bottom are l1, l2, l1, l2

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how that is even functioning. The switch loop should go between Com & L1 [or also L2 if it's a two-way switch] The left switch Is using L1 & L2 which will never make contact with each other, they alternate connection  to Com & never each other. The right-most switch would appear to be incapable of doing anything at all, as there's only one wire connected, nothing to close the loop. At least nothing should go bang, but if that is currently working, ring a sparky. Something is badly wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Tetsujin S/He put in the notes "Common words removed on first pic." I assume meant "wires".

Answer (score 0):

The left side of the new switch (viewing it from the back) is the same as the old one.  Wire it just the same.

The right side of the new one is upside down by comparison.  Look at it the other way up, and it becomes the same again.

Comment: The existing setup should just not work at all. There is something seriously wrong if it does.